# Is overriding to_s methods in Ruby bad?

Tags: ruby

I've been experimenting and find that I like redefining Object's `to_s` methods.

Is this a bad idea or is it good practice?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

No, you should feel free to override `to_s` - there are no ill side-effects. As long as your new `to_s` is more informative than the built-in (not exactly a high standard there), you're in the clear.

And they help make your test failures read better - sometimes by a lot - which is never a bad thing. Go for it!

Comment: I would even go as far as saying that overriding `to_s` to something more meaningful is *good* practice!

Answer (score 12):

I override `to_s` all the time in my Rails project:

```
   def to_s
     first_name + " " + last_name
   end
```

so that it's easier to show objects in the view:

```
<%= @person %>
```

Answer (score 9):

It might be tricky to do that because sometimes, `inspect` method just calls `to_s`, and if that is altered, you might have trouble debugging. If you think altering `to_s` may confuse you when you need to see the results by methods that rely on `inspect` , such as `p`, then maybe you need to redefine `inspect` for that class at the same time. As long as you are sure what you are doing, you might want to do it.

Answer (score 0):

It's not "bad" per se, but it isn't "good" either. It really depends on the context.

If you are doing this for a one-shot place (for example inside your rails app's `/lib/` folder, for a particular app) it is probably alright (make sure to give the file a descriptive name, such as `object_to_s_patch.rb` or similar, and that all patches are on the same place)

If you are doing a gem or a lib, on the other hand, I would not override it. Instead I'd add another method - `Object.to_special_s` or something. But I'd also try not to touch Object if possible - If you can get by with using `YourModule::to_s(object)` that'd be probably even better.

The reasoning behind this is that other people might be using `Object.to_s` for other stuff, maybe in other libs. Monkeypatching it will produce clashes with those other libs.

The only exception when doing a gem that I can think of is when the main point (or one of the main points) of that library is actually overriding the method; in other words, you are literally making a lib that overrides `Object.to_s`, and little else. I'd put some big warning on the documentation on that case. This way people using it will not get surprised.

Comment: I may be mistaken, but I think the OP was defining `to_s` in his own custom objects, not opening Object and modifying that.

Comment: Oh. Well yes, if you are overriding `to_s` in your own classes, that's totally OK.

Comment: Thanks Magnar for clearing that up!